# Property accessibility in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Here is what we know from the docs: getter of `public` property can't be private (seems logical enough), so:

```
@Inject
var repository: MyExampleRepository? = null
    private get
```

won't compile.
Ok, so maybe we can make property `private` and define setter `public`?

```
@Inject
private var repository: MyExampleRepository? = null
    public set
```

This will compile and value will actually be injected, but I still can't use this in code, so:

`service.repository = null`

gives compilation error:

```
Kotlin: Cannot access 'repository': it is 'private' in 'MyService'
```

I wonder if it is possible to have private property with public setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue: [KT-10385](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10385):

> Kotlin doesn't generate setter method for the following code:
>
> ```
> private val someProperty: Integer
> public set
> ```
>
> The intention is to generate a set only property. Use case including
>   spring dependency injection.